# My test web app is showing up error, I am using nginx in Dockerfile - ingress in kubernetes minikube

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying ingress resource in kubernetes (minikube). I have created pod and NodePort service and it works fine when I `curl 192.168.99.100:30290`

then I created ingress with / path and it still works fine if I add `curl **-kL** 192.168.99.100`

But when I add /anypath in ingress paths path it return error page when I `curl **-kL** 192.168.99.100/anypath`

`kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-web
  labels:
    app: test-web
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-web
      image: aamirpinger/test-web
      ports:
      - containerPort: 80 # default nginx port`

`---`

`kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-web-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-web
  ports:
  - port: 8080 
    targetPort: 80 # default nginx port
  type: NodePort`

`---`

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pwa-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /anypath
        backend:
          serviceName: test-web-service
          servicePort: 8080`

## Resource List


`kubectl get pod,svc,ingress
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/test-web   1/1     Running   0          7m`

`NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes         ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          11m
service/test-web-service   NodePort    10.98.17.107   <none>     8080:30290/TCP   7m`

`NAME                             HOSTS   ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
ingress.extensions/pwa-ingress   *       10.0.2.15   80      7m`





**## curl -kL 192.168.99.100/anypath**

## Received following Result

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.15.5</center>
</body>
</html>
```

## Expected following Result

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

anyone who know what I am missing in above to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your web app handle this path? From the nginx side everything seems to be ok, it handles the request.
You could try the "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /" annotation so the nginx will rewrite the desired target in the request.

Comment: My web app image has just 1 file "index.html" which prints Hello World, My Dockerfile has 2 lines From nginx COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html. I have tried annotation but still the same

Comment: you where right. I was doing annotation since many hours but somehow missed starting "niginx." and was writing from ingress.kuber...... Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

If you manually start the docker container with nginx with port 80 exposed as some local port, does it work navigating to /anypath ? Do you have access to nginx access logs from your pod ?

Comment: test-web pod logs are as follows

172.17.0.8 - - [17/Jan/2019:17:35:59 +0000] "GET /test1 HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" "192.168.99.1"
2019/01/17 17:35:59 [error] 5#5: *25 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.8, server: localhost, request: "GET /test1 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.100"

Comment: kube-system nginx pod logs are as follows
192.168.99.1 - [192.168.99.1] - - [17/Jan/2019:17:35:59 +0000] "GET /test1 HTTP/1.1" 308 187 "-" "curl/7.58.0" 83 0.000 [default-test-web-service-8080] - - - - bd8874bcdb81eca1a05ecf7650a74b7b
192.168.99.1 - [192.168.99.1] - - [17/Jan/2019:17:35:59 +0000] "GET /test1 HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "-" "curl/7.58.0" 35 0.001 [default-test-web-service-8080] 172.17.0.9:80 153 0.001 404 41568e53ca0172e76f46319adab355b1

Comment: technically I am missing something as what I understood is ingress just redivert to u to service with respect to URI, but what I am witnessing here is its looking for folder or route, which is not there in image as it got single index.html file in the root...

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh!!! Finally got my answer. annotation: "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /" I was doing annotation but missing "nginx." in the start which was only cause of error and took my whole day. The purpose of this line is actually to redirect to root from any route we write ahead of curl . As root is the place where normally we have our entry point i.e. index.html in my case.